# Wrap user input text in a created element inside contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a contentEditable div as so:

```
<div id="content" contentEditable="true"></div>
```

What I would like to have happen is when the user starts typing some text, I want that text to be wrapped within a `div` or `p` tags.  I can add html to the "content" div but the typing is done outside the created div.

```
function keyPress(e) {
    if (e == 'undefined') e = window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        //close the div or p tag or just exit out of it
    }
}
function mainFocus(e) {
    if (e == 'undefined') e = window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (!target.innerHTML) {
        //var div = document.createElement("div");
        //$id("content").appendChild(div);
        //or $id("content").execCommand("insertHTML", false, "div");
        //inserts the div but typing is outside the newly created tag
    }
}
```

Right now when I start typing inside the div, the text isn't wrapped.  If I press enter and start typing again, the second line text is wrapped in a div.  I want to have control from the start so the first line text will be wrapped as well.  Also if the user pushes the insert image button, the previous text should end with a closing tag.  I'm doing this in Chrome right now.  I'm new with this contentEditable div so I'm trying to get the hang of it.

UPDATE: From more and more playing around, I guess I'm ok with keeping the functionality of contentEditable.  The only thing I have a problem with is the initial text which is written is not enclosed within any tags.  If I press Enter, the next line is enclosed within `div` tags.  How can I enclose the first text within `div` but keep the functionality standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I came up with, and it's not perfect, is to disable default functionality of `contentEditable` and wrap everything onblur:

```
function keyPress(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<br><br>");
                return false;
            }
        }
        function wrapText(_callback) {
            var target = $id("content");
            for (var i = 0; i < target.childNodes.length; i++) {
                (function(i) {
                    var curNode = target.childNodes[i];
                    if (curNode.nodeName === "#text") {
                        var element = document.createElement("span");
                        element.setAttribute("id", i);
                        target.insertBefore(element, curNode);
                        element.appendChild(curNode);
                    }
                })(i);
            }
            _callback();
```